# How to chain append in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char chars[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int f = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    string pwd;
    string attempt;

    cout << "Type the password: ";
    cin >> pwd;

while (a < 26) {
    attempt = chars[a];
    a = a + 1;
    if (attempt == pwd) {
        cout << "The password is: " << attempt;
        break;
    }
    if (a >= 26) {
        a = 0;
        break;
    }
}

while (a < 26 && b < 26) {
    attempt =  "";
    attempt.append( 1, chars[a] ).append( 1, chars[b] );
    b = b + 1;
    if (attempt == pwd) {
        cout << "The password is: " << attempt;
        break;
    }
    if (b >= 26) {
        a = a + 1;
        b = 0;
    }
    if (a >= 26 && b >= 26) {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        break;
    }
}

while (a < 26 && b < 26 && c < 26) {
    attempt =  "";
    attempt.append( 1, chars[a] ).append( 1, chars[b] ).append( 1, chars[c] );
    c = c + 1;
    if (attempt == pwd) {
        cout << "The password is: " << attempt;
        break;
    }
    if (c >= 26) {
        b = b + 1;
        c = 0;
    }
    if (b >= 26) {
        a = a + 1;
        b = 0;
    }
    if (a >= 26 && b >= 26 && c >= 26) {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I am confused with attempt.append

This works:

```
    attempt.append( 1, chars[a] ).append( 1, chars[b] );
```

But this doesn't:

```
    attempt.append( 1, chars[a] ).append( 1, chars[b] ).append( 1, chars[c] );
```

It doesn't display the text.
Can you please help.
How do you chain multiple appends? I have looked everywhere but I can't understand the solution. This is a brute force program and I know it is probably the most inefficient one. If you do have a simpler solution, please tell me!
Thanks.

Comment: What does "But this doesn't" mean?  Do you get a compilation error?  Something during execution?

Comment: No it doesn't come up with an error, it just doesn't display the text. Sorry for not describing the error

Comment: `char chars[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` is much shorter `:)` of course `char chars[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` will allow you to treat `chars` as a `c-string` which would make life easier.

Comment: @David C. Rankin Thanks but how do i use that? I am completely new to c++.

Comment: It looks like you are testing whether `pwd` is made up of all lower chars, then whether it contains something not a lower char, etc.. The `strspn` and `strnspn` functions can help greatly as long as you nul-terminate `chars` (making the c-string functions able to take it as a parameter) This is a bit of an  **XY Problem**. See: [**What is the XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Where do you see any lowercase conversions or tests? This is a straightforward, if highly repetitious, password guesser, that just brute forces passwords of length 1, then 2, then 3 and so on until it guesses what the user entered. Kinda pointless since the user gave them the password anyway, but it seems like you're commenting on a completely different question...

Comment: `attempt = chars[a]; ... if (attempt == pwd)` If the possible 'set' of `chars` is `a-z`, the password cannot contain anything other than `a-z`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: That's not a particularly useful criticism though. You could just as easily point out it can't guess passwords with spaces or punctuation. Brute-forcing passwords composed solely of lower case ASCII letters is a reasonable exercise.

Comment: No complaint on the exercise, and it was not intended as off-hand criticism, the purpose was to insure that I wasn't missing a larger point when looking at the question, because it, in and of itself, looked like it was attempting to do something larger than what it was asking. Good job in picking up on it being just what it was and nothing more, I was trying to read more into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `attempt.append( 1, chars[a] ).append( 1, chars[b] ).append( 1, chars[c] );` (well, aside from it being a relatively slow/verbose way to do the simpler C++11 initializer list approach of `attempt.assign({chars[a], chars[b], chars[c]});`). You've got a logic error elsewhere.

Looking closer, the error appears to be in the final `if` of your *second* `while` loop (the one testing two character passwords):

```
if (a >= 26 && b >= 26) {
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    break;
}
```

That `if` only fires if *both* `a` and `b` reach `26`, but the prior `if (b >= 26)` ensures that when `a` hits 26, `b` is reset to 0, which terminates your loop when `while (a < 26 && b < 26)` is evaluated with `a == 26` and `b == 0`.

Thus, you reach your third loop with `a == 26` and `b == 0`. `while (a < 26 && b < 26 && c < 26) {` immediately determines that `a` is not less than 26, and the loop is never entered at all.

A simple fix for this is to explicitly reset your loop variables before each `while` loop begins, e.g. `a = b = c = 0`. This would also allow you to remove the otherwise unnecessary final `if` in each loop (allowing the `while` condition to handle exiting the loop without resetting indices within the loop itself).

Comment: To be clear, there are many other improvements that could be made (a doubly-nested loop, where the outer loop iterates over possible lengths, and the inner iterates over passwords of a given length would dramatically reduce the code size and complexity). The answer above is intentionally minimalist, covering the specific problem in the question and the simplest fix.